# Is there a way to schedule automated data upload for a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, automation

I'm using R to read excel files from a folder, transform it, and then upload that data as a .RData file to be used in my flexdashboard with a shiny runtime. I then upload/update the flexdashboard to shiny servers to run as a web application. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to automate this process.

I want my R code to run at specific time intervals (every 2 hours), export the data to the folder housing my shiny dashboard, run the shiny dashboard and upload it to shiny servers to update.

Is there any way i can automate this process? Below is my currrent workflow for reference

Add excel sheet to Folder A --> excel sheets imported into R and transformed to usable data (Project housing R script in Folder B) --> export .RData to Folder C where shiny app will use the data --> run the app and upload/update it to shiny servers

Comment: Do you have any portion of that process automated? (1) Can you automate the data acquisition part? Once you have a function/script that "just gets the data", then ... (2) Can you automate updating your shiny dashboard? Finally, it should be straight-forward to automate uploading to a shiny server. (4) Once that is resolved, then the answer to your *"every 2 hours"* (from a local computer) is likely resolved with Task-Scheduler (windows) and/or `cron` (most other systems).

Comment: What is your "shiny server", are you using `shinyapps.io`, an instance of Posit Connect, or something else?

Comment: @r2evans currently none of the process is automated. i have to manually open R and run the code to transform it, then manually run the flexdashboard and manually upload it to ```shinyapps.io``` to host it.

Comment: Let's define "automate" for the purpose of my questions: when you load/source your `script.R`, do you have to make _any_ changes to it, or do you just "Source file" and everything (in a step) is complete? Do you have "oops" moments, where something in the data requires manual intervention that is not handled by conditions in the code?

Comment: @r2evans no i dont have to make any changes to it at all. the code is already built to handle any conditions and just a matter of running it.

Comment: Okay, so literally all that needs to happen is that some R process somewhere sources your `script.R`, and everything you need is done, correct?

Comment: @r2evans I guess so yeah

Comment: So we're back to my first comment: if you're on Windows, look into Task-Scheduler (there is an R package for it, I have never used it); if not Windows, look into `cron` for running it, and perhaps `cronR` for interfacing with `cron`.

Comment: @r2evans I've looked into ```cron``` but the only downside to it is that I need to have my computer on the whole time, but id like for it to run even when my computer is off. Would using google cloud to mitigate this be a good option then?

Comment: It seems as if the only change is that you are updating data that your app sources via a simple file. Perhaps you can include the data-acquisition `script.R` (not deployment) into your shiny app, and have a simple check that says if the data file is more than 1 day old, run that script.

Comment: @r2evans Okay so basically write the code I have in ```script.R``` into the shiny app and then just have it run the code through there every half day for example? how would i do that if it gets data from an external folder?

Comment: For organization, I would likely have it as a separate `.R` file, and make it a one-call (no-argument) function; if it takes more than a half second and/or you have a high volume of concurrent users, then I suggest you need a mutex, perhaps something like `getdata <- function() { lock <- filelock::lock("path/.lock", timeout=0); if (is.null(lock)) return(); on.exit(try(filelock::unlock(lock), silent=TRUE), add=TRUE); do_rest_of_stuff_here(); }`. This will prevent the function being called in two different shiny sessions, potentially clobbering each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you move the "update data" process to *within* your shiny app, and restrict how often that will be triggered. When your shiny app starts, call the below `getdata()` to load the data (inner code is all yours), and it should self-govern so that it won't update data more than once within the period (1 day = 86400 seconds), etc.

Up front: there is some simple locking and safeguarding, I suggest that your function should be a bit "noisy": if the data needs to be renewed, I suggest adding a message so that you can see in the logs when it's being called. Similarly, you may need to wrap some portions in `tryCatch` so that the function *always* returns the previous data if there is a problem with the current data. A little outside the scope here, and perhaps unnecessary if your current process is robust enough.

I suggest a method where your shiny app attempts to get new data if the data file is older than a limit (e.g., 1 day). I suggest adding a new `.R` file to your app, something like:

```r
#' Return data from file, optionally renewed if "out-dated"
#'
#' @details
#' This should almost "always" return the data stored in
#' the file, whether out-dated or not. It will return the
#' existing data (and not attempt to renew) when:
#'
#' - the file is younger than `renew` seconds old
#' - the file is out-dated but the lock is held by
#'   another process
#' 
#' This will return `NULL` if the file does not exist
#' and the lock is held by another process. Otherwise,
#' it should retrieve the new data.
#'
#' @param file character, full path/filename of the data
#' @param renew numeric, number of seconds (age of the file) before
#'   attempting to download new data and save in-place
getdata <- function(file = "path/to/saved_data.rds", renew = 86400) {
  lockfile <- paste0(file, ".lock")
  if (file.exists(file)) {
    age <- difftime(Sys.time(), file.info(file)$mtime, units="secs")
    if (isTRUE(age <= renew)) {
      dat <- try(readRDS(file), silent = TRUE)
      if (inherits(dat, "try-error")) {
        warning("problem reading file: ", conditionMessage(dat))
      } else return(dat)
    }
  }
  lock <- filelock::lock(lockfile, timeout = 0)
  if (is.null(lock)) return() # no action, another process is retrieving data
  on.exit(try({ filelock::unlock(lock); unlink(lockfile); }, silent=TRUE), add = TRUE)
  ## do the rest of your work here
  ## (for now, I'll just make some random data)
  newdata <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), size=4),]
  ## pick up from here
  saveRDS(newdata, file)
  newdata
}
```

Demo that it "caches" for up to `renew` seconds:

```r
getdata("~/Downloads/quux.rds", renew=5)
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# Volvo 142E        21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
getdata("~/Downloads/quux.rds", renew=5)
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# Volvo 142E        21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Sys.sleep(5)
getdata("~/Downloads/quux.rds", renew=5)
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```

I'm using the `.rds` format here for a single dataset; alternatives:

- if your process is simply downloading a `.csv` file, there should be no need to do anything fancy, just `download.file("https://...", file=file)` and then do your `read.csv(.)` to read the data;
- if your process needs multiple datasets on a renewal, then you may want to pass `envir=` instead, and use `save(obj1, obj2, obj3, file=file)` and `load(file, envir=envir)`

There is also the `cachem` package that does object-caching with optional age constraints. It works very well for that purpose, but there are two reasons I chose to not use it here:

- when data is expired, all processes that need it will get "nothing" and therefore try to retrieve/regenerate it themselves, no mutex; and
- when data is expired, it is truly unavailable, meaning there is no easy way to get "stale data" while another process is retrieving/generating new data ... this may actually be a desirable trait depending on data needs, but I did not infer from your question that this was the correct behavior.